# Grails 3.3.0 /Gorm: how to do a query with a join

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am sure this is easy, but cant find any example for this in the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/GORM.html) or google.

Say we have customer and account domain objects thus:

```
Class Customer {
   String name
}

Class Account {
   Customer customer
   BigDecimal balance
   Currency currency
}
```

If I was not using grails, and had no ORM, I would be doing something like this in raw SQL:

```
 Select c.name, a.balance
 from customer c, account a 
 where name like xxx 
       and a.customer_id = c.id
```

or even:

```
 Select c.*, a.balance, a.currency_id
 from customer c, account a 
 where name like xxx 
       and a.customer_id = c.id
```

or even:

```
 Select c.*, a.balance, cur.iso
 from customer c, account a, currency cur 
 where name like xxx 
       and a.customer_id = c.id
       and cur.id = a.currency_id
```

However in grails, I am looking for a way to return a set of Customers with the Accounts already loaded.  that way I can pass Customer objects back to the view, not lists of strings.

**This must be done as a single query, not as one query to get all the customers, then a query per customer to get their balance (there may be millions of customers)**

I know that grails does lazy loading, and if I wanted to I could force grails to load the account each time I query a player, but this would affect times when I want to look up customers but dont need the balance.

I also know I can hard code SQL/HQL in grails, and just return the result as strings for the gsp page to render, but this is not very grails like.

Also, I dont want to add a link in player to many accounts as this can have serious performance implication, and is not a general solution (I have around 400 domain objects and need a join query solution for many of them).

Note, this example assumes that there is an account per player. If this became not true, I would use an outer join if I was doing it via SQL. No idea what the equivalent is in GORM.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Updating answer since I hadn't read properly.

To start with you mentioned doing a `gorm` or `HQL` query in the view. This maybe one day you will thank me for but you should really try to keep presentation as presentation. The moment you are attempting to do finds or complex decision making it is time to step back and think does concept need rethink or if not possible how to implement this logic into a `taglib` that either does work or then relies on service to do the work.

So far as what you need the most simplest answer is to amend the Customer class and do a custom Set/Let that grabs object belonging to other object:

```
Class Customer {
   String name

   Set<Account> getAccounts() { 
         return (Account?.findAll{customer==this} as Set<Account>)
          /// Or write hql you can also add things like take to limit it
         //return Account?.findAllByCustomer(this)?.take(5)
   }
   Account getAccount() { 
         return Account?.find{customer==this} 
   }

}
```

Then when you are iterating through all your users

```
<g:each in ="${instance.customers}" var="customer">
${u.name} vs ${customer?.account?.balance} ${customer?.accounts?.balance}
</g:each>
```

The getters will only be called when you hit each user

Alternatively try writing it all as one query that gets everything possibly does a group by in the query or outside of query however it works and pass in the offset and max values then list it so you then use pagination to control so many records, the basics of a HQL query would be something like this (Since you want all the users that may or may not have a balance and customer doesn't have a relation with account)

```
String query= """Select new map(c.name as name, a.balance as balance) 
 from Customer c, Account a
 where name like :name
  and a.customer.id = c.id
"""


Map mp=[:]
name='%'+params.name+'%'

def result=Account.executeQuery(query,mp,[readOnly:true])
```

Comment: So grails/gorm doesn't have a way of retrieving player and account objects in one go?  The above would be my last resort, as it means I cant re-use any of my templates or views as they expect proper Customer and Account objects rather than an arbitrary result set.  The above case is so common in my app (wanting to return objects which have a join), if grails cant handle it it does vastly reduce its value.

Comment: ofcourse it does but you had started the question with an sql query so an answer was give to suite your query needs i added a findAll method that can do similar

Comment: The crux of the problem is that Customer.findAll(..) wont load the balances from the accounts.  In the GSP, if I try to display the balances, e.g. ${customer[x].account.balance) would presumably do another query to the DB.  Loading all the accounts with Account.findAll wont give me a collection of Customers I assume, so not sure how this would help.

Comment: updated answer you should look at a full hql query if this is a user listing with pagination queuekit/queuemail plugins on my repos has an example